# Kate SQL Plugin Missing MySQL

Tags: kate

I installed the kate SQL plugin, but there are no options in the dropdown for Oracle or MySQL.  The only option is something called QSQLITE.

Does anyone know how to get MySQL and Oracle to work with this tool?

Answer (score 0):

Late response and I'm sure you have your answer by now but this will help if not..
http://www.pythian.com/blog/using-katesql-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database-in-kate/